# UPDATE mysql without reloading Javascript/Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

This code works great but only update on page refresh. If somebody knows how to do the same thing using Ajax/js.

> My php code:

```php
 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['place_bet'])) //IF BUTTON HAS BEEN PRESSED   {

   if ($_POST['bet_value'] <= $balance && $_POST['bet_value'] > 0) //BET VALUE MUST BE POSITIVE AND < OR = THAN BALANCE
   {
       $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE users SET balance=:newbalance');
       $req->execute(array(
       'newbalance' => $balance - $_POST['bet_value'],
       )); 
   } else {
       //VALUE NOT ACCEPTED
      }
}
?>
```

> My html code:

```html
<input type="text" class="css-input"  id="bet_value" value="0"> //TEXT BOX
<div class="btn-play" onclick="MyFunction()" name="place_bet">Bet</div>
```

> Js:

```js
function MyFunction(){
$.ajax(.........................

}
```

Comment: You could simply update the corresponding field on `success`.

Comment: `$.ajax(.........................` — You need to read an introductory guide on using that function.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://yourphpfile.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {place_bet: yourVariable},
    success: function (data) {
        $("#divToRefresh").html(data)


    }

});
```

Careful your php must return an HTML view that will be inserted in `$("#divToRefresh")`

Comment: How do I return an html view ?

Comment: Insert HTML code like `echo '<p> Hello world </p>';` in the php file.